# How do I add 1 to a datarow that is being cast as an object

Tags: c#, dataset

I am querying an access database to get a quantity. Here's my code:

```
  this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.garysInventoryDataSet.Inventory);

  CurrentRow = (from x in garysInventoryDataSet.Inventory
    where x.InventoryId == InventoryId
    select x).FirstOrDefault();

  if (CurrentRow == null)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Inventory Item Not Found.");
  }

  yearToDateQuantityTextBox.Text = CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"].ToString();
```

When the user clicks a button, I want to increment this number by 1:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"]++;
}
```

The CurrentRow line is being cast as an object and won't let me add to it directly. Can I somehow safely cast this to an int so that I can add to it?

What's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can't increment an object like that;

```
CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"]++;
```

You should cast to int and increment it;

```
CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"]) + 1;
```

Comment: ok I was overthinking it, I was concentrating on the left side when I should have been looking at the right side. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as` operator:

```
int? count = CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] as int?;
CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] = count + 1; //null + 1 is null
```

Or just:

```
CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] = (CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] as int?) + 1; //null + 1 is null
```